# Recursive sequences general term

Tags: sequences-and-series, recursion

Find general term for nth term of the sequence
$$a_{n+2}=a_{n+1}+a_n+n^2, a_1=1, a_2=2$$ How to approach this type of questions? I am looking for a specific answer but also more general insight about solving such questions would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you familiar with characteristic equation?

Comment: Yes, but this must be solvable with use of them and thus would appreciate answer without them

Comment: Have you tried a generating function approach?

Comment: not exactly i am not familiar with this method

Answer (score 1):

I probably made some error computing this but the general approach can help
$$a_{n+2}=a_{n+1}+a_n+n^2\\a_{n+1}=a_n+a_{n-1}+(n-1)^2\\a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}=a_{n+1}-a_{n-1}+2n-1\\a_{n+2}=2a_{n+1}-a_{n-1}+2n-1\\a_{n+1}=2a_n-a_{n-2}+2n-3\\a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}=2a_{n+1}-2a_n-a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}+2\\a_{n+2}=3a_{n+1}-2a_n-a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}+2\\a_{n+1}=3a_n-2a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}+a_{n-3}+2\\a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}=3a_{n+1}-5a_n+a_{n-1}+2a_{n-2}-a_{n-3}\\a_{n+2}=4a_{n+1}-5a_n+a_{n-1}+2a_{n-2}-a_{n-3}$$
Hence you can do the characteristic equation now

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** The general solution is the sum of the solution of the corresponding homogeneous equation $a_{n+2}=a_{n+1}+a_n$  and a partial solution 
 which you may  looking  in the form of a polynomial  of degree  $2$  with  uncnown  coefficients.

The situation is very close  to solution of the linear  differental equations.

Comment: this polynomial will be $n^2+3$ or what? Could you tell me what will be this polynomial equation?

Comment: i am still waiting for the answer